# Is there a way that we can emit error or success manually on Future dart?

Tags: asynchronous, dart, future

Something like **SettableFuture/ListenableFuture java** where we can control what to emit to the listener.

What I want to have is :

For example, I have a socket connection active.

1. I `send`(request) a message through socket in some function
2. The request also has its response, but it comes through `onData(d)` callback some where else not in this request funtion
3. I store the future in a key-value array after `send`
4. After the response on `onData(d)` I will get the future from the array and make it emit success or error appropriately

Comment: You could wrap the `Future` in a `Completer` and use the `Completer`'s `Future` instead.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I don't need to wrap it with the future, I wrap it with the actual return type. Anyway, you can post this as an answer. And thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can make an asynchronous function either return a value (success) or throw an exception (either by `throw`ing from a `async` function or by manually returning a [`Future.error`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/Future.error.html)).

If you have some existing `Future` that you don't control, you can't force it to succeed or to fail.  You instead could make callers wait on a `Future` that you *do* control, and you could make your `Future` depend on the external one.

[`Completer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Completer-class.html) can simplify some of that for you.